# how to update reusable nested donut chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a reusable chart with a data update function--following the suggestions from this article by Rob Moore: https://www.toptal.com/d3-js/towards-reusable-d3-js-charts --which I am calling *pizza*.

Pizza is a nested donut chart. It looks like a pie chart with concentric rings. I would like to add an interaction whereby a user can click on a slice of the pie and the selected slice will expand to fill the whole pie.

The chart has two setter functions: .data() and .numberOfRings().

Pizza.data(*dataArray*).numberOfRings(*n*) results in a chart with *n* concentric rings and *dataArray.length* many slices, where *dataArray* is an array of integers.

*n* copies of *dataArray* are passed to d3.pie() to determine the startAngle and endAngle for each eventual arc in each of the *n* slices. Then the objects returned by pie are assigned outerRadius, innerRadius and some other useful properties, based on their indexes:

```
const ringSet = [...Array(numberOfRings).keys()].reverse()

const sliceGenorator = Object.fromEntries(ringSet.map((x, i) => [i, 
data]))

const pie = d3.pie().sort(null)
const arc = d3.arc()

let arcs = d3.values(sliceGenorator).map((d, i) => 
                              pie(d).map((x, v) => 
        ({
            ...x,
            arcSlice: 'slice_' + v,
            arcRing: 'ring_' + i,
            innerRadius: cWidth * i,
            outerRadius: cWidth * (i + 1),
            id: 'ring' + i + '_' + 'slice' + v
        })));
```

these objects then get passed to an arc generator and appended to the svg group.

```
const flatArcs = arcs.flat()
const paths = svg.selectAll('path.arc')
    .data(flatArcs)
    .enter()
            .append('path')
    .attr('class', 'arc')
            .attr('d',d => arc(d))
    .attr('id', d => d.id)
    .attr('fill', d => function that colors slices)
```

My idea is to update the chart data with an index array, as shown below:

```
let data = [30, 22, 8, 10]

//create an instance of the chart. call it 'pizza'
const pizza = pizzaChart()
  .numberOfRings(5)
  .data(data); 

//render the pizza into the div
d3.select('#container')
  .call(pizza)

//returns an index array
function selected(d) {
  let zeros = new Array(data.length).fill(0);
  zeros[d.index] = 1;
    return zeros}

//pass an index array to pizza as the data update
d3.selectAll('path.arc')
  .on('click', d => pizza.data(selected(d)))
```

Say the user selects slice 1, then *indexArray* = [0, 1, 0, 0] is passed to pizza's updateData function, which runs the same processes described above, producing a new array of arc objects whose start angles and end angles have been calculated from the values in *indexArray*.

The paths are then updating the chart with the arc id's as a key, to proved object constancy.

```
// update the data and pass in the arc id's as a key
const updatePaths = d3.selectAll('path.arc')
             .data(updateArcs.flat(), d => d.id)

updatePaths.enter()
     .append('path')
     .attr('class', 'arc')
     .attr('d',d => arc(d))
     .attr('stroke', '#334646')
     .attr('id', d => d.id)
 .attr('fill', d => function to color code by slice)

updatePaths.exit().remove();
```

I expect that the arcs in the selected slice will be re-rendered with startAngle = 0 and endAngle = 2*PI, while the other arcs will be re-rendered with StartAngle = 0 and endAngle = 0. Thus the  selected slice will fill the chart while the other slices will collapse. But nothing happens.

I will eventually add an animated transition, but I only want to do that once I get the expected behavior out of the chart.

if I `console.log(updatePaths.data())` see the expected data.

Am I on the wrong track? Am I missing something obvious?

Any help would be deeply appreciated

here is a link to my full code:

https://bl.ocks.org/AveryBurke/d366090ccc19c41c8ee7be2958b3f425/46540a46380d7f7eb8ced458e6eda06c2c05f2d2

Answer (score 1):

You were not updating existing items at all -- all your actions were upon new items selection `updatePaths.enter()`, and none upon `updatePaths`.

I added a merge, and it started doing what I think you wanted it to

```
updatePaths.enter()
    .append('path')
    //actions for only new items; things that never change
    .attr('class', 'arc')
    .attr('stroke', '#334646')
    .attr('id', d => d.id)
.merge(updatePaths)
    //actions for both new and existing items
    .attr('d',d => arc(d))
    .attr('fill', d => sliceColor.range(pallet[d.index])(arcRingValue(d)))
```

Comment: that was it! Thank you. I think I sill need to wrap my head around what 'merge' is doing.

Comment: @Avery it simply joins two selections into one, kinda like array concat in plain js. The merge here is between two selections that have no common elements (`.enter()` has *only* new elements, the other one has *only* elements that existed before update). Generally you'll almost always use such merge. Also note, that this applies to d3v4, watchout if you see examples from older versions.